# validating json fields

Tags: django-rest-framework

This is my serializer file

```
from rest_framework import serializers

#All validations here
class BudgetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    start_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    end_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    lifetime_budget = serializers.FloatField(max_value=None, min_value=None,allow_null=True)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['start_date'] > attrs['end_date']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("start_date must be less than end date")
        return attrs  
class IoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        name  =  serializers.CharField()
        state =  serializers.CharField()
        currency = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
        budget_type = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
        budget_intervals = BudgetSerializer(many=True)
```

Json which i am serializing has 1000's of fields but i only want to validate few fields and return all json fields.But problem with serialzer is that it only outputs json consisting of mentioned field in serialiser.

Like i am sending json with 1000s of object names but it only return json which consist of start_date,end_date,lifetime_budget,name because it is mentioned in serializer file.I wanted to only validate few fields so i wrote them in serializer file but only this fields are returned.

My views.py code

```
class InsertionOrderViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request, format=None):
        advertiser_id = request.query_params.get('advertiser_id', None)
        data = json.dumps(request.data) 
        io_object = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda x: namedtuple('io_object', x.keys())(*x.values()))
        serializer = IoSerializer(data=request.data, instance=io_object)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) 
        response_data = IO.create(data=request.data, params={"advertiser_id": advertiser_id })
        return Response(request.data)
```

Comment: I have tested commenting out the line `response_data = IO.create(data=request.data, params={"advertiser_id": advertiser_id })` of the ViewSet. It works fine. I guess there are some routing issues in your urls or you might have previously inherited from `APIView` instead of `ViewSet` and tried to register that as router. Also you're returning request data not the validated data from serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`serializers.data` method will only return values which are supplied to it unless you declare some `read_only` fields and or do any of these - supply an instance during serializer initialization, return an instance from `serializer.save` method. When `serializer.instance` has a value then `read_only` fields are returned with `serializer.data`. Your use case suggests that the incoming JSON object has 1000s of data of which only a small portion requires validation. My suggestion will be not to pass all the data, pluck only the necessary portion of the data, send them to serializer and do validation, return `serializer.errors` if any else rejoin the `serializer.data` with the incoming JSON and return the JSON. Since, majority of the data has nothing to do with validation, passing them in to the serializer will cause significant performance issue due to the way `drf-serializer` validates and maps values.

Still if you still want to supply all of the JSON to serializer and validate only a few consider supplying an instance when initializing serializer, dynamically declare `ReadOnlyField` in your `serializer.__init__`

`serializers.py`

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

# default attributes of objects
default_attrs = ['__doc__', '__module__', '__slots__', '_fields', '_source'] 

class BudgetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    start_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    end_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    lifetime_budget = serializers.FloatField(max_value=None, min_value=None,allow_null=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BudgetSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        for attr in dir(instance):
            if attr not in self.fields and not callable(getattr(instance, attr)) and attr not in default_attrs:
                self.fields[attr] = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['start_date'] > attrs['end_date']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("start_date must be less than end date")
        return attrs
    

class IoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name  =  serializers.CharField()
    state =  serializers.CharField()
    currency = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    budget_type = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    budget_intervals = BudgetSerializer(many=True)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IoSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        for attr in dir(instance):
            if attr not in self.fields and not callable(getattr(instance, attr)) and attr not in default_attrs:
                self.fields[attr] = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
```

inside `views.py`

```py
import json
from collections import namedtuple

# inside view
data = json.dumps(request.data) 
io_object = json.loads(data, object_hook=lamdba x: namedtuple('io_object', x.keys())(*x.values()))
serializer = IoSerializer(data=request.data, instance=io_object)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) 
print(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I think it's being returned from your view? Can you show the codes inside your view?

Comment: I have edited my answer to fix the no attribute named kwargs issue. Your other issue is being thrown from your viewset not the serializer. Please ask separate question with viewset, serializers, urls and request payload.

Comment: it would do so because in namedtuple we named any instance as 'io_object'. Since you are have not declared any serializer for nested political_content object it’s returning just the namedtuple instance for political_object wihout serializing it